# Find a small integer m such that $(182+m)^2 -33127$ is a perfect square. And show that there are exactly two values of m.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying this problem. I want to ask is there any other way to find the value of m except for trying m=1,m=2....

---

For the second part of the question, after getting: 
$33127=157 \times 211$. You need to show that 157 and 211 are prime; may I know what could be the quick ways to testing whether a 3-digit or 4-digit number is prime.

Thank you very much for the reply.

Comment: what is $n{}{}{}?$

Comment: For such small numbers, trial division will barely be beatable.

Comment: Presumably you mean non-negative integers?

Comment: Sorry, n is 182.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have $$(182+m)^2-33127=k^2\\(182+m-k)(182+m+k)=33127=157\cdot 211\\
182+m+k=211\\182+m-k=157\\
k=27\\m=2\\ \text{or}\\
182+m+k=33127\\182+m-k=1\\k=16563\\m=16382$$
To show $157,211$ are prime you can just use trial division.  You only need to go up to $13$ and there are easy divisibility rules for most primes up to $13$, so it is not much work.

Comment: Thank you very much. So this problem mainly involves trying.

Comment: I think the hard part is finding $33127=157\cdot 211$.  The above is just turning the crank once you have that.  Clearly they are not even, the digits do not sum to a multiple of $3$, they do not end in $5$ and we are already halfway to proving them prime.

Comment: Does $16382$ qualify as a small value of $m$?  If not, there is only one value that works.

Comment: Milliiikan Thank you. I think so, I spent lots of time to find m=2. So, to test whether n is a prime, I just need to make sure that it would leave a remainder when dividing integer smaller than $\sqrt{n}$ .

Comment: The other value of m might not be small, I think.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Suppose that $(182+m)^2-33127=n^2$. Then 
$$
33127=1\cdot 33127= 157\cdot 211=(182+m-n)(182+m+n).
$$

Comment: Thank you. But, how could you find m, if you don't know they are 157 and 211. What I do is putting in the number, and try. May I know is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Did you mean $2\color{red}11$?

Comment: If you don't want to factor $33127$ you can indeed guess how big $m-n$ and $m+n$ should be and after a short trial find $m+n=29$ and $m-n=-25$. But why not factor $33127$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I think so, thank you very much for the remind.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes, I think so, too. Thanks!

Comment: @Dietrich Burde Thank you very much.

Comment: Modular arithmetic, shows $m$ is not 1 mod 3.  It's also either of 0,2 mod 4 . you could probably check mod 8 to solve it to just one of those.